# Dynamically drawing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to create a simple, purely JS program for drawing in a canvas. I have an acceptable solution right now, but if I draw very quickly, my drawing pen isn't continuous and I get scattered circles, probably because the computer can't keep up with the pace.

```js
var draw = false;

function yesDraw() {
  draw = true;
}

function mouseCoordinates(e) {
  if (draw) {
    var x = e.offsetX;
    var y = e.offsetY;
    drawing(x, y);
  }
}

function noDraw() {
  draw = false;
}
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function drawing(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="400" ; width="1000" onmousedown="yesDraw()" onmousemove="mouseCoordinates(event)" onmouseup="noDraw()" onmouseout="noDraw()" style="border: solid 1px black;">Your browser does not support canvas.</canvas>
```

Is there any way to get a continuous flow of drawing and still keep it 100% JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a smooth continuous line with mouse using html canvas and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650306/how-to-draw-a-smooth-continuous-line-with-mouse-using-html-canvas-and-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Line segments from previous mouse position.

Rather than draw arcs draw line segments from the previous mouse position to the new one. As you don't want the line to be drawn from the end of the previous draw, you also need to indicate when a new line starts and set the previous mouse position to the current mouse.

To do this I added 3 variables `lineStart`, `lastX`,and  `lastY`

`lineStart` is set to true when the mouse down event fires. In the draw function if line start is true then the `lastX` and `lastY` are set to the `x`,`y` and `lineStart` is set to false.
`lastX`, `lastY` hold the previous mouse position. They are set to `x`,`y` at the end of every draw call.

The line segments need to have the 2D context properties `ctx.lineWidth` set to the line width. To ensure the line is continuous the `ctx.lineCap` property is set to `"round"`. This adds a semi circle to the start and end of the line.

#### Drawing past the edge

Having the pen turn off when the mouse moves out is annoying, you do this because if you don't you lose the mouse up events and the mouse keeps drawing with the mouse button up.

If you add the mouse to the `document` rather than the canvas, you don't have to worry about the mouse going outside the frame. You will still get the mouse up events even if the mouse is completely of the tab and browser.

Though you will have to use a slightly different way of getting the mouse coordinates, as you will want to still draw while off the canvas by at least half the draw line width. See code on how to get the mouse coordinates.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const r = 10; // draw radius
ctx.lineWidth = r * 2;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
var draw = false;
var lineStart = true;
var lastX, lastY;
function yesDraw() { draw = true; lineStart = true }
function mouseMove(e) { 
   const bounds = c.getBoundingClientRect();
   const x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
   const y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
   if(draw && x > -r && x < c.width + r && y > -r && y < c.height + r){
      drawing(x,y);
   }
}
function noDraw() { draw = false }
document.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseMove);
document.addEventListener("mousedown",yesDraw);
document.addEventListener("mouseup",noDraw);
function drawing(x, y) {
  if(lineStart){
     lastX = x;
     lastY = y;
     lineStart = false;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
  lastX = x;
  lastY = y;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="400" ; width="1000" style="border: solid 1px black;">Your browser does not support canvas.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [lineTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) and end each line in an [arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) to make continuous smooth lines.

```js
//Create Canvas
//(You can do this in HTML)
var c = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
c.height = 400;
c.width = 1000;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
//Control drawing variable
var drawing = false;
c.onmousedown = c.onmouseout = c.onmouseup = function(evt) {
  drawing = (evt.type === "mousedown");
};
//Keep track of last position
var oldX = null;
var oldY = null;
/**
 * Draw the latest line
 *
 * @param {number} x
 * @param {number} y
 */
function draw(x, y) {
  if (drawing) {
    if (oldX !== null) {
      //If drawing, move to old coordinates for continual line
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(oldX, oldY);
    } else {
      //Else simply move to current coordinates
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      ctx.beginPath();
    }
    //Draw a line
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    //Add an arc to the end of the line to make it smooth
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 0, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    //Save new coordinates as old for next draw cycle
    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;
  } else {
    //If not drawing, cut line byt setting "old" to null
    oldX = null;
    oldY = null;
  }
}
//Bind drawing
c.onmousemove = function(evt) {
  draw(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY);
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: It would provide a better answer if you tested your code before posting. Also line segments can have rounded ends `ctx.lineCap = "round"` so you don't need to add the arc, and there is no need to have `ctx.closePath()` as that will only create another line segment back to the start of the line. `ctx.closePath` is not the opposite action to `beginPath` it creates a line from the last path position back to the start (either previous first point after `ctx.beginPath`, or previous `ctx.moveTo`)